# C++ Smart Pointers Scope and Resource Deleting

Tags: c++, function, scope, c++14, smart-pointers

I have the following simple code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class resource
{
public:
   void print() { cout << "Class Still Alive" << endl; };
};

resource* create_resource()
{
   std::unique_ptr<resource> r = std::make_unique<resource>();
   return r.get();
}

void execute_resource(resource* r)
{
   r->print();
}

int main()
{
   resource* r = create_resource();
   execute_resource(r);
   return 0;
}
```

The unique ptr `r` created in `create_resource` goes out of scope at the end of the function. At least this is my understanding of scope.

So how is the actual resource wrapped by the unique pointer still reachable and does create a segmentation fault since its owning unique pointer should have gone out of scope and deleted this?

Compiling using: `g++ test.cpp -std=c++14`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, your understanding is correct about the function scope. The `std::unique_ptr<resource>` will be destroyed after the `create_resource` function scope.

---

> So how is the actual resource wrapped by the unique pointer **still**
> **reachable and does create a segmentation fault since its owning unique
> pointer** should have gone out of scope and deleted this?

Because of the reason mentioned above, what you receiving here in the `main`

```
resource *r = create_resource();
```

is a dangling pointer. Accessing it will cause the [undefined bahviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) and hence anything can happen. In your case, it is a segmentation fault.

---

In order to fix the issue, you can return the `std::unique_ptr<resource>` itself from the `create_resource` function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <memory>

class resource
{
public:
   void print() const // can be const
   { 
         std::cout << "Class Still Alive\n";
   };
};

std::unique_ptr<resource> create_resource()
{
   return std::make_unique<resource>(); // return the std::unique_ptr<resource>
}

void execute_resource(resource* r)
{
   r->print();
}

int main()
{
   auto r = create_resource();
   execute_resource(r.get()); // pass the pointer to execute!
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> The unique pointer r created in create_resource() goes out of scope at
> the end of the function. At least this is my understanding of scope.

That is correct -- when `create_resource()` returns, the `std::unique_ptr`'s destructor executes and deletes the `resource` object that it is holding.

> So how is the actual resource wrapped by the unique pointer still
> reachable and does create a segmentation fault since its owning unique
> pointer should have gone out of scope and deleted this ?

`create_resource()` is returning a dangling pointer -- that is, a pointer to the memory location where the `resource` object previously was located, but since the `resource` object was deleted, the pointer is no longer usable.  Attempting to use dereference the dangling pointer will result in undefined behavior, including in some cases a segmentation fault.

The correct way to handle this situation is to have `create_resource()` return a `std::unique_ptr<resource>` instead of a `resource *`.

Answer (score 0):

> The unique pointer r created in create_resource() goes out of scope at the end of the function. At least this is my understanding of scope.

Your understanding is correct.

> So how is the actual resource wrapped by the unique pointer still reachable

This assumption is wrong. It is **not** reachable anymore after the function returns.

The behaviour of the program is undefined. It calls a member function through an invalid pointer.

Comment: Thanks to all for the replies. So my take away message is that the fact that the above code did not trigger a segfault as I was expecting is purely because it is undefined behaviour and I just got "lucky" the member function was still accessible through an invalid pointer as you clearly explain above.

Comment: @FieldtestoFieldtest Or "unlucky" :)